# A div should always be 100% height - either viewport or content. Followed examples online and still stuck!

Tags: html, css

I have [viewed the source of this page](http://www.dave-woods.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2008/01/full-height-updated.html) and applied it to [my page](http://www.golfballbusters.com/~new/).

In FireFox and Safari, I can't for the life of me get the main container to be the height of the viewport. There is always an ugly margin down the bottom.

I have inspected all I can with Firebug, which seems to tell me that neither `html`, `body` or `#mainContainer` have the correct height.

I have done this countless times before, but now I am making modifications to an older site and can't seem to get it to work.

Please someone point me in the right direction.

Thanks muchly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `overflow:hidden;` on #pageContent. Seems like it's either not containing floats or something is overflowing

**EDIT**: You have a min-height of 430px and a height of 460px on #homePage. Can't you leave the height as auto?

Comment: Ah, seems to have nailed it! Thanks meder. Now to go back to this somewhat awful CSS...

Comment: Yeah, there are a few less than best practices so far I have uncovered. Thanks for the update.

Answer (score 0):

Your page is XHTML while the example page is HTML.

You have to add this to your page:

```
<style type="text/css">
    html, body {
        height:100%;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: His page is XHTML with a Content-Type of `text/html` and he already has 100% height on html AND body.

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS has the `#homePage` height set to 460px.  I removed this in Firebug and the page stretched to the bottom, though your footer would need some adjustment.